# SQL Insert/Update Issue

Tags: sql

I am trying to update one table from another, im able to update fine as long as the customer record exists, but there are some entries that dont.

To solve this i've tried running the following insert

```
SELECT * 
INTO SalBudgetCust 
FROM SalBudgetCust_temp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Customer 
    FROM SalBudgetCust 
    WHERE Customer = SalBudgetCust_temp.Customer
)
```

but im prompted with

```
There is already an object named 'SalBudgetCust' in the database.
```

Im stuck at this point... could anyone offer a little guideance?

Answer (score 5):

`SELECT INTO` implicitly creates the table you name. You should instead use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM ...`, so that the existing table is used.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `INSERT INTO` instead of `SELECT * INTO` ... like

```
INSERT INTO SalBudgetCust SELECT * FROM SalBudgetCust_temp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT Customer FROM SalBudgetCust WHERE Customer = SalBudgetCust_temp.Customer
)
```

Comment: I've just tried that, coming back with the error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.  Ive confirmed that the table names are all correct.

Comment: Sorry ... small mistake. Edited ... try now.

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax to insert data of one table into another is :

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
SELECT * FROM old_table 
WHERE some_condition;
```

Where, new_table is the table where you want to insert data, old_table is table from where you are fetching data and some_condition is the expression / condition based upon which you want to fetch data from old table.

You may use other clauses like `order by`, `group by`, and even sub queries after where clause.

May refer this [`SQL INSERT INTO`](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/insert-statement/sql-insert-command.php) and it's subsequent pages.